# Wrong FS on loading json with spark from s3

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3, geospatial, amazon-emr

I'm trying to load geojson file with spark and [magellan library](https://github.com/harsha2010/magellan)
My code for loading is:

```
val polygons = spark.read.format("magellan").option("type", "geojson").load(inJson)
```

Where inJson is path to my json on s3:
s3n://bucket-name/geojsons/file.json

Error with stack trace:

> 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, ip-172-31-19-102.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor 1): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS:
>   s3n://bucket-name/geojsons/file.json, expected:
>   hdfs://ip-172-31-27-182.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:653)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getPathName(DistributedFileSystem.java:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.access$000(DistributedFileSystem.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:299)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:312)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:773)    at
>   magellan.mapreduce.WholeFileReader.nextKeyValue(WholeFileReader.scala:45)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)    at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)    at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)    at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.fold(TraversableOnce.scala:212)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.fold(Iterator.scala:1336)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$fold$1$$anonfun$20.apply(RDD.scala:1086)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$fold$1$$anonfun$20.apply(RDD.scala:1086)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1980)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1980)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The problem occurs only when I run it on more than one machine, so it works fine on EMR cluster with master and 1 instance in core group, but fails like that with 10 instances in core group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be problem within Magellan `WholeFileReader`. It was getting default FileSystem.

It was solved with [this pull request](https://github.com/harsha2010/magellan/pull/115)

The solutions was like so:

```
-      val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
+      val fs = path.getFileSystem(conf)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on EMR, you can just use "s3://bucket/path" instead of "s3n://...."

Comment: Tried it before, doesn't make a differenc